# Communicating with a flash server using rtmp without Flash

Tags: flash, rtmp

I want to talk to a flash server which uses RTMP, but I don't want to use Flash, but rather c# or java.

I was looking at Red5 but their client API seems to be a bit wobbly.

Does anyone have any other ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

["RTMP: Flash video streaming protocol"](http://captsolo.net/info/blog_a.php/2009/01/19/rtmp_flash_video_streaming_protocol) discusses libraries and applications for communicating with RTMP servers.

The main protocol code from the [RTMPDump utility](http://rtmpdump.mplayerhq.hu/) for downloading RTMP video streams is now available in its own library, librtmp (used by FFmpeg, MPlayer, and XBMC media center).

Note: the RTMPDump utility was originally based on the the libRTMP library, a part of the XBMC project.

Comment: the original libRTMP code from XBMC (from 2008 or earlier) can be found at: http://xbmc.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/xbmc/tags/8.10_Atlantis-linux-osx-win32/XBMC/xbmc/lib/libRTMP/

Comment: funny how the code goes around and now the library is used by XBMC itself. after a while history forgets which was first :)

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at commercial JUV Client (http://www.smaxe.com/juvclient.jsf) library
that lets you communicate with rtmp enabled servers.

Comment: amazing tool! worth the money!

Answer (score 4):

There's a python implementation of the RTMP protocol, [RTMPy](http://rtmpy.org/). Other than that and Red5, I don't know of any other RTMP client implementations. (Well, besides flash itself of course).

What flash server are you using? Some of them allow you to communicate with other protocols as well, such as text-based or XML-based, and those might be better to use than RTMP if your client is not flash-based.

Answer (score 4):

I also started developing a C++ RTMP server. I'll make a C++ client library as well in the near future and, of course, C#,Java and Lua wrappers. Stay tuned on [this site](http://rtmpd.com) or you can become a group member [here](http://groups.google.com/group/c-rtmp-server) and get informed right away.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a c# rtmp implementation at https://code.google.com/p/rtmp-mediaplayer/

It is tested to work on Windows, iOS and Android. You need bass (http://www.un4seen.com/bass.html) to output audio.

Answer (score 0):

If you like you can use Opencv. Then you can do all sort of real time video processing. I have answered same king of question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30096327/opencv-wont-capture-frames-from-a-rtmp-source-while-ffmpeg-does/32249336#32249336)