# How do you read an RTMP stream through Javascript only?

Tags: javascript, rtmp

We would like to use an RTMP data stream(not video) on the mobile platforms that do not support flash (iOS etc). Since Java is also not an option for some mobile phones, we are looking at creating a Javascript rtmp client. This is not for iphone/ipad applications, but rather for use in the Safari browser application, accessed by an HTTP url.

Does anyone know the best place to start of this, or if one already exists? Thanks!

Comment: In all the research we did, it appears that same origin policy http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy restrictions will become an issue using this through CDNs, as we won't be able to set the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header on the response from the edge servers, which will stop us from being able to make the necessary handshake through RTMPT. reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/

Answer (score 1):

Try [RTMP-dump](https://github.com/BigBadOwl/iPhone-Rtmpdump).

See also: [Communicating with a flash server using rtmp without Flash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154749/communicating-with-a-flash-server-using-rtmp-without-flash)

Comment: I looked through this, and it appears to be for applications. I need this to work on the client safari web browser. Not within an application. I believe the RTMP-dump is for use inside an application.

Comment: It's not free, but http://www.digital-life.cz/en/rtmp-protocol-library/blog could potentially be what you need.

Comment: Thanks Matt. I'll have a look.

Comment: Just wanted to follow up about digital life. Their response to my questions was "it is written in Objective-C for iOS platform. I don't think it's possible to write library like this in javascript. 
RTMP client is pretty much a server and cost a lot of interactions, which has to be performed in real time through socket (like packet parsing, multiple stream logic, control messages and Shared Objects)"