# How to play RTMP video in phonegap Cordova :video extension SDP

Tags: cordova, video-streaming, html5-video, phonegap-plugins, rtmp

I am developing a mobile application for a radio station, I am using `cordova/phonegap` and I need to stream a `RTMP` Live video with the extension `.sdp`.

Here is an example of my Link that provides the video :

```
rtmp://streaming.toutech.net/live/radio.sdp
```

I tried the  html 5 `video` tag but it didn't work.

I tried some accustomed `js` plugins but it didn't work either.

Any help will be really appreciated .

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Like it was mentioned, the issue is that you will require Flash to use RMTP on the client side.

That said, using Flash is a terrible idea for mobile and perhaps not future proof.

I would suggest looking into WebRTC and transcoders. WebRTC does not support RMTP, it streams SRTP encrypted with DTLS, but I believe some broadcasting media servers support this conversion (from RMTP to VP8 WebRTC enabled).

Look for the Wowza solution (http://www.wowza.com/forums/showthread.php?36532-WebRTC-support or http://www.wowza.com/products/addons/wowza-transcoder-addon)

Your best bet is to find a transcoding solution that can work with the browsers and hopefully WebRTC capable.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue here might be that RMTP on the client side requires Flash Player. One bet might be to use [video.js](http://www.videojs.com/) which [supports RMTP](https://github.com/videojs/video.js/commit/7ab3d190f2ea6d03a659d5b08d8fc4d369f919b4) using [FlashJS](http://flashjs.com/).

Otherwise you could refer to this really old discussion about [communicating with a Flash server over RMTP without Flash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154749/communicating-with-a-flash-server-using-rtmp-without-flash) (in C# or Java).

Answer (score 1):

Web Browsers don't support communication over TCP sockets yet. (There are few proprietary APIs, e.g. mozTCPSocket) You can use RTMPT instead to get audio/video packets using XHR.

When you receive video packets, you will need to combine them into some container, e.g. Fragmented MP4... and then play it using MediaSource extensions. The MSE and fMP4 are new to all browsers and only few can support it properly, however you can try demo at http://areweflashyet.com:8082/mse/demo-mse2.html in Firefox (37+?) and Chrome (40+?).

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/jumpbytehq/cordova-jb-plugin-panframe

Not tested by myself, but seems work.